# Type mismatch: SiteEdit.ComponentPresentation

Tags: tridion

We are using Tridion 5.3. Recently we setup new Content Manager Server and Content Delivery server (5.3).

When we try to publish page, page is getting failed with error.

> Error 13 occurred while rendering the Page: Type mismatch: 'SiteEdit.ComponentPresentation' (source:         sLeft = sLeft & SiteEdit.ComponentPresentation(objCP, sMoveLeftRail )).

We have installed SiteEdit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error typically occurs if your version of SiteEdit has been compiled against a different Tridion version. So you need to ensure that you have installed the correct version of SiteEdit which is compatible with 5.3.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. I will check and get back.

Comment: On the server where it is working fine below are the version details
Version : CM Explorer 5.3 - Build 5.3.0.63,  
CMS : 5.3 - Build 5.3.0.993 
cm_SiteEdit.dll version is 1.3.0.1052 (using "Details" button available in the dialog box)

On the server where it is NOT working below are the version details
Version : CM Explorer 5.3 - Build 5.3.0.1012,  
CMS : 5.3 - Build 5.3.0.1219 
cm_SiteEdit.dll version is 1.3.0.1052 (using "Details" button available in the dialog box)

It seems that with both versions we are using same siteedit, do we need to change it, if yes how to find compatible version.

Comment: They are using the same SiteEdit version, that's true. But they are different Tridion versions. It looks like the one that isn't working has a service pack installed. So you probably need a SiteEdit version that works with that service pack. I recommend contacting Customer Support once it is absolutely clear which version of Tridion you are supposed to be using.